# A plugin by the name "getServiceLocator" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager

Tags: banco-de-dados, doctrine-2, zend-framework-2

recentemente comecei a aprender Zend Framework2 com AngularJS através de um curso da School of Net. Tendo em vista o ano do curso, que se não me engano é de 2013, algumas coisas mudaram em ambos os frameworks. Logo, deparei-me com um problema ao utilizar o seguinte trecho de código para testar a conexão com o banco de dados e listar os registros usando Doctrine 2:

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function indexAction() {
        $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        $repo = $em->getRepository('Entity\Categoria');

        $categorias = $repo->findAll();

        return new ViewModel(['categories'=>$categorias]);
    }
}
```

Quando executo a aplicação, retorna o seguinte erro:

> A plugin by the name "getServiceLocator" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager

Além disso, uma informação adicional:

> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException

E o arquivo de onde, aparentemente, a mensagem provém:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso de ZF2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\AbstractPluginManager.php:133

Até onde sei, o problema origina-se do fato de que o método `getServiceLocator()` fora retirado das versões mais recentes do Zend Framework 2. Porém, não tenho a mínima ideia de como resolver para que eu possa continuar meus testes e passar adiante no curso. Alguém me pode dar uma luz?

Comment: Exato. Você não pode mais usar o getServiceLocator, você deverá criar uma Factory para a sua Controller e injetar nela as suas dependências. Neste caso o EntityManager do Doctrine.